# SQL query to get current and last year sales and their difference in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table Sales:

```
year total_sale
2015 23000
2016 25000
2017 34000
2018 32000
2019 33000
```

This has to be the result

```
year current_total_sale previous_total_sale difference
2015 23000              NULL                NULL
2016 25000              23000               2000
2017 34000              25000               9000
2018 32000              34000               -2000
2019 33000              32000               1000
```

Comment: For Oracle you can use lag function. Refer - https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

Answer (score 3):

Query using lag for the desired result -

```
select year_1, total_sale as current_total_sale, 
lag(total_sale) over (order by null) as previous_total_sale,
total_sale - lag(total_sale) over (order by null) difference
from sales;
```

DB fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ce42333005544d2e4c487c218524b2f4)

Comment: Good answer (and upvoted it), but I think "order by null" is a bit ugly, I would prefer "order by year_1"

Answer (score 0):

Self join, join the table to itself.

```
select a.year, a.total_sale as current_total_sale, b.total_sale as prev_total_sale,
b.total_sale - a.total_sale as difference
from have as a
left have as b
on a.year = b.year+1
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE sales (yr,total_sale) AS
SELECT 2015, 23000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2016, 25000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2017, 34000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2018, 32000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2019, 33000 FROM DUAL; 

select curr.yr, curr.total_sale, prev.total_sale as previous_total_sale, 
curr.total_sale - prev.total_sale difference
from sales curr
LEFT JOIN sales prev ON curr.yr = prev.yr + 1
ORDER BY curr.yr;

YR  TOTAL_SALE  PREVIOUS_TOTAL_SALE DIFFERENCE
2015    23000    -   - 
2016    25000   23000   2000
2017    34000   25000   9000
2018    32000   34000   -2000
2019    33000   32000   1000
```